# Run command while making it think `sudo` doesn't exist

Tags: shell, sudo

I use a program (`yay`, in archlinux) which uses `sudo` to elevate privileges. However, if it doesn't find `sudo`, it will switch to `su`, which is what I want it to do, since my user is not a sudoer, but I do have `sudo` installed (because there's another program which needs `sudo` to be installed even when run as root, I know it's silly).

Now the question is, how can I run this program (`yay`), while making it think `sudo` doesn't exist?

Note that `yay` is a package manager (AUR helper) which also builds and installs packages from source, and you can't do those builds as root, for security reasons, which is fair enough.

Also note that I've already opened an issue [here](https://github.com/Jguer/yay/issues/1614) on `yay`'s repo, but while that's being fixed, I'd appreciate an alternative solution.

Comment: Can't you just run it as root? I mean `su -c yay`?

Comment: Unfortunately not, since package builds from source can't be run as root.

Comment: I was thinking you could just remove `sudo`'s directory from your PATH when launching `yay`, but that won't work since on Arch, `sudo` is in `/sbin` which is just a symlink to `/usr/bin` and removing that would mean none of the scripts called by `yay` will work. If adding your user to `sudoers` isn't an option, I fear you're stuck and will have to modify yay to remove the `sudo` check.

Comment: I have to assume that you've read the manual of `yay`.  In there there is the mentioning of a `--sudo` option that takes the command to call instead of `sudo`.  When you try `yay --sudo su`, how does it fail? Did you alse try modifying the `su` command in this way by means of the `--sudoflags` option?

Comment: `yay --sudo=su` just doesn't do anything, no fail, no message, just exits.

Comment: @adrin does `yay --sudo=/sbin/su` do any better?

Comment: nope, nor does `yay --sudo "/sbin/su" --sudoflags "-c"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only workaround I can think of without modifying `yay` itself would be to have a wrapper script which you will launch as root and which will temporarily remove `sudo` before launching `yay`:

```
#!/bin/sh

su -c "mv /sbin/sudo /sbin/sudo.old" && yay "$@"
su -c "mv /sbin/sudo.old /sbin/sudo"
```

That will ask you for the root password twice though. Another option is to just run the script as root and then in the script, use `su` to switch to another user:

```
#!/bin/sh

normalUser="$1"
shift

mv /sbin/sudo /sbin/sudo.old &&
su -c "yay $@" $normalUser
mv /sbin/sudo.old /sbin/sudo
```

You would then run this as:

```
su -c "/path/to/yay.wrapper.sh adrin $yayArguments"
```

This should be safe in your case since you don't actually use `sudo`, but I would still make a copy of `/sbin/sudo` so you can easily get it back if something goes wrong, just in case.

Comment: While this might work, I think this is suboptimal - `yay` can be running for a very long time (potentially hours while it builds heavier packages), and for all that time sudo won't be available (OP mentioned at least one "some other program" that requires sudo).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to bypass this problem will be to use the `--sudo=su` option.

**tl;dr** - run `yay --sudo=su -Syu` to achieve the desired effect.

Explanation why `yay --sudo=su` didn't do what you expected is below.

---

The issue is due to the way `yay` handles CLI arguments. From the docs:

```
If no arguments are provided 'yay -Syu' will be performed.

If no operation is selected -Y will be assumed.
```

If no arguments are provided `yay -Syu` is performed (full system update), but `--sudo=su` counts as an argument, so yay selects the `-Y` operation (list packages matching the query, which is empty in this case, and thus the command exits immediately).

Here's the piece of code responsible: https://github.com/Jguer/yay/blob/next/pkg/settings/parser/parser.go#L618

Comment: This perfectly solves my issue. But I think the general question is still valid, even though I don't need it now for my current use case.